# Insert shortcode in the middle of an external page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying a page from vendor's server on my website, and would like to use shortcodes to style the layout of the content, this page has a url `http://mysite.com/vendor_page`.

I did some research and understand that I can use [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) to echo the shortcode, but not sure how I can use it on an external page where there is no actual content I can edit with my WordPress visual html editor.

Kinda lost here and hope someone can point me a right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `do_shortcode()` function in a `template/php file` you have to first create/register a `shortcode` in your `functions.php` like

```
add_shortcode('my_test_shortCode', 'my_test_shortCode_func');
function my_test_shortCode_func()
{
    return "my_test_shortCode_func working...!"; // or whatever you want
}
```

Then in your template/php file you can directly call it like

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_test_shortCode]');?>
```

As a result it'll echo `my_test_shortCode_func working...!` at the place of `do_shortcode`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going to give it a try, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

From [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website):

> In order to transform regular PHP pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.
>
> ```
> <?php 
> /* Short and sweet */
> define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
> require('./wp-blog-header.php');
> ?>
>
> <?php
> require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
> ?>
> ```

I've never tried this, so I'm not sure where to locate the file, but after it's included you should get access to the Wordpress functions. Pass any strings that contain shortcodes through `do_shortcode()` and you'll get the result with the replaced shortcodes.